# Trying with php to change state of database assuming if state is 1 then its processed .So i need to fetch all data with stae 0 and change to 1

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Trying with php to change state of database assuming if state is 1 then its processed .So i need to fetch all data with stae 0 and change to 1.

```
array(3) {["sender"]=>string(6) "wandia"["receiver"]=>string(4) "john"["user_id"]=>int(1)}
```

```
array(3) {["sender"]=>string(11) "test_sender"["receiver"]=>string(13) "test_receiver"
["user_id"]=>int(123</pre{"status":"error","description":"fopen(http://127.0.0.1:8080/inbox/give): Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!"}
```

`public function actionProcess()
{
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;

    try {
        // Fetch outbox data with state = 0
        $outboxData = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('
            SELECT *
            FROM inbox
            WHERE state = "0"
        ')
        ->queryAll();

        foreach ($outboxData as $data) {
            // Create JSON payload
            $payload = [
                'sender' => $data['sender'],
                'receiver' => $data['receiver'],
                'user_id' => $data['user_id'],
                // Add other fields as needed
            ];
            echo '<pre>';
            var_dump($payload);
            echo '</pre>';
        }
        $http = new Client();
         //Send POST request to outbox/give
         $response = $http->createRequest()
                ->setMethod('POST')
                ->setUrl(['http://127.0.0.1:8080/inbox/give'])
                ->setData($payload)
                ->send();

            // Check if the request was successful
            if ($response->isOk) {
                // Update outbox state to 1 and save
                Yii::$app->db->createCommand('
                    UPDATE inbox
                    SET state = "1"
                    WHERE id = :id
                ')
                ->bindValue(':id', $data['id'])
                ->execute();
            }
            return ['status' => 'ok', 'description' => 'success'];
        

        // Return success response
        
       
    }catch (Exception $e) {
                 // Handle exceptions
                 return ['status' => 'error', 'description' => $e->getMessage()];
            }
        }`

Comment: Typically one might use syntax similar to `state=1-state` (assuming values of 1 or 0 ) to toggle between said states.

Comment: You could also use `xor` (exclusive or) to toggle between 0 and 1. See [this example](https://dbfiddle.uk/P4hTQB4C).

Comment: @Nadia001 what Paul proposed I think this is a not good way to work with db to escape internal Active Record commands. This is not a Symfony, knowing that it related to its components. Yii2 AR models have more efficient and embed commands to update multiple records at once.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have model named `Inbox`, so than you can do it thit way:

```
$inbox = InboxModel::updateAll([
     'state' => true,
], ['id' => 1]); # condition
```

This way, yii prepare sql and execute it the right way using AR methods